# Floating an algorithm?

Tags: floats, captions, algorithms, algorithmicx, acm

I'm typesetting an algorithm using the `algorithmx` package as follows:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{\textsc{Whatever}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  ...
\end{algorithm}
```

However, I would like it to float like a figure. If I replace `\begin{algorithm}` with `\begin{figure}` it does float as I like, however, the caption does not look as pretty any more (I presume it is redefined by a `sig-alternate` class I am using for the whole document).

Is it possible to have both a nice caption and floating behaviour at the same time?

Comment: Have you looked into using the float package?

Comment: Yes, thank you, it does work. I'll put this as an answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Thanks to Harald's advice I found the following two-line solution to my problem:

```
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{algorithm}{t}{lop}
```

This was sufficient to make all my algorithm blocks to float exactly as I needed them to.

See also: ["float" package reference](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/float/float.pdf).

Comment: Add `\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithm}` to capitalise the float name.

Answer (score 11):

The [LaTeX Wikibook section on algorithms](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms#Typesetting_using_the_algorithmicx_package) explains this very nicely:

> The algorithmicx package provides a number of popular constructs for algorithm designs. Put `\usepackage{algpseudocode}` in the preamble to use the algorithmic environment to write algorithm pseudocode (`\begin{algorithmic}...\end{algorithmic}`). You might want to use the algorithm environment (`\usepackage{algorithm}`) to wrap your algorithmic code in an algorithm environment (`\begin{algorithm}...\end{algorithm}`) to produce a floating environment with numbered algorithms.

Meaning, you only need to add `\usepackage{algorithm}` and your code snippet will be rendered as a floating figure.

Answer (score 3):

Just importing the `float` package and keeping the optional float argument makes the algorithm float. E.g.,

```
\usepackage{float}
...

\begin{algorithm}[t]
  \caption{\textsc{Whatever}}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
  ...
\end{algorithm}
```

Replace `[t]` with `[b]` if needed.