# Create floating subsection

Tags: floats, sections-paragraphs

[image: My summary - just to get an idea]

I am writing a summary mostly including equations but also some pictures. Now I would like to place the subsections including these pictures floating, such that the arrange themselves nicely.

I know how to place floating pictures. But is it possible to do the same to a whole subsection?

Thanks for your answers!

Edit: The floating section works. Altough in combination with {multicol} the newfloat{subsec} is no longer displayed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,caption,graphicx,float,titlesec}
\usepackage{multicol} %multiple columns
\newfloat{subsec}{h}{lop}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\section{The Section}
Here is my non-floating introduction, which I place here just to 
demonstrate the margins.

\begin{subsec}[ht]
\subsection{Veni}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{subsec}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: A float, in the LaTeX sense, must fit on a single page.  So when you say "floating subsection", do you envision that this subsection must always appear in its entirety on a single page?

Answer (score 3):

**REVISED ANSWER**

With the original answer (floated subsections and margin notes), I was unable to get `multicols` to encapsulate `floats`, and I don't see how that is possible.  So, while the OP speaks of floats within columns, this revised answer takes a slightly different interpretation.

If the OP's goal is for subsections to remain as intact blocks, then one alternative to floating them would be to put them each in their own `minipage`, which will not break across columns.  That is the approach I adopt here, but it also puts an added constraint on the OP to keep subsections under column in length.

My `\mpar` alternative to `\marginpar` is adopted here, as well, but adds an optional argument `l` or `r` to indicate which column the call is made from.  In theory, 3 or more columns could be handled with a further rewrite.

So here is the result of this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,caption,graphicx,tabto,multicol}
\newenvironment{subsec}[1][]{\par\noindent\begin{minipage}{5.9cm}}{\end{minipage}}
\def\mmargin{20pt}
\def\mwid{3cm}
\def\mposl{\dimexpr-\mmargin-\mwid}
\def\mposr{\dimexpr\textwidth+\mmargin}
\newcommand\mpar[2][l]{\tabto*{\csname mpos#1\endcsname}\smash{\parbox[t]{\mwid}{%
  \raggedright#2}}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\begin{multicols}{2}
\section{The Section}
 Here is my non-floating introduction, which I place here just to 
  demonstrate the margins.
\begin{subsec}[ht]
\subsection{Veni}
\lipsum[1]
Margin note call \mpar{Here is my longish margin note}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subsec}
\begin{subsec}[ht]
\subsection{Vidi}
\lipsum[3]
Margin note call \mpar[r]{Here is my second longish margin note}
\lipsum[4]
\end{subsec}
\begin{subsec}[ht]
\subsection{Vici}
\lipsum[4-5]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-A}
\captionof{figure}{My Figure}
\end{center}
\end{subsec}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Perhaps something like this...  Here I create a new float, `subsec`, using the answer described at [Floating an algorithm?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6157/floating-an-algorithm/6166#6166).  Note that you cannot then place floating figures inside of the subsections, but can nonetheless get them there with `\includegraphics` and `\captionof` techniques, as I show on the final float.

As I mentioned in my comment to the OP's question, LaTeX floats must fit on a single page.

I have verified that it works when inserting `\tableofcontents` and `\listoffigures` at the top of the document.

Based on comment by the OP, EDITED to provide faux margin note `\mpar` capability (using the `tabto` package), by specifying `\mpos` for the location relative to the left margin of the text, and `\mwid` for the margin-note width.  I just set the margin note as normal text, but `\mpar` can be easily adjusted for font size and style.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,caption,graphicx,float,tabto}
\newfloat{subsec}{h}{lop}
\def\mpos{\dimexpr\textwidth+20pt}
\def\mwid{3cm}
\def\mpar#1{\tabto*{\mpos}\smash{\parbox[t]{\mwid}{%
  \raggedright#1}}\tabto*{\TabPrevPos}}
\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents
%\listoffigures
\section{The Section}
 Here is my non-floating introduction, which I place here just to 
  demonstrate the margins.
\begin{subsec}[ht]
\subsection{Veni}
\lipsum[1]
Margin note call \mpar{Here is my longish margin note}
\lipsum[2]
\end{subsec}
\begin{subsec}[ht]
\subsection{Vidi}
\lipsum[3]
\end{subsec}
\begin{subsec}[ht]
\subsection{Vici}
\lipsum[4-7]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=2in]{example-image-A}
\captionof{figure}{My Figure}
\end{center}
\end{subsec}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, your solution is working wonders!
Where I'm starting to get problems is when combining it with the package {multicol}.

I get the error:
Package multicol Warning: Floats and marginpars not allowed inside `multicols'

Do you have an Idea how to make this work?

Comment: @GianAndreaMüller I have developed a fake `\marginpar` substitute called `\mpar`, as described in my revised answer.  I am no user of `multicol`, but will give that issue some additional thought, as well.

Comment: @GianAndreaMüller Could you clarify how you are hoping to use `multicol`?  As in 1) use `multicol` inside of subsections or 2) use subsections inside of `multicol`?

Comment: @GianAndreaMüller I cannot make floats work inside of `multicols`.  However, I propose an alternative using `minipage`s instead of floats.  Would that possibly work for you?

Comment: I was using multicols to divide my landscape-page into 3 colums. Like globally. Within these columns I wanted to have the floating subsections, hoping that they would arrange in a space-saving way... 
Maybe minipages would do the job - I will try it of course... :)

Comment: @GianAndreaMüller One thing to keep in mind, which applies to both floats and minipages, they will appear (in the output document) in the same order as they appear in the tex file input.  So, if you are envisioning a shuffling of the subsection order in order to achieve a better fit on the paper, that will not happen using either technique.

Comment: I have just added a snapshot of my summary for you to get an idea. 
of course i could change the order of the subsections to work around the layouting problem - but it is my ambition to make latex do that on its own.

Comment: @GianAndreaMüller Here are two loosely related questions, I think:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69560/what-is-the-best-way-of-arranging-multiple-minipages-on-a-page, and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168748/optimal-arrangement-of-pictures-boxes-in-a-page.